# How can I string replace results of a command in one line?

Tags: bash, replace, grep

For example, let's say I wanted to replace the substring `python` with `php` on the output of `ps aux | grep python`.

How can I do this in one line?

```
ps aux | grep python | /python/php/
                              ^--- totally made up
```

Desired output is to see strings that look like this: `script.python` to `script.php`. This has nothing to do with the actual files. It's just about output. I could've just as easily said replace all `ph` with `f`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't even need `grep`. You can just use `sed`:

```
ps aux | sed -n '/python/s/python/php/pg'
```

- `-n` will suppress normal output
- `/python/` will search for lines with `python`
- `s/python/php/pg` will replace all occurrences of `python` with `php` and print the replaced lines